# addition of count ,sub total ,if currency is same using arraylist

Tags: java

Below is a sample list items..which consist of 1* 10 =10 (count * currency = sub total)
i want to add count , sub total ,if currency is same.

for example

```
1 * 10 = 10
3 * 10 = 30
```

after list checking final lsit must be 
4 * 10 = 40.

```
public class CashModal {


    private int count;
    private int currency;
    private int subTotal;  
gettter/setter
}


        listItems.add("1 * 10 = 10");
        listItems.add("2 * 10 = 20");
        listItems.add("1 * 5 = 5");
        listItems.add("2 * 10 = 20");

           cashModals=new ArrayList<CashModal>();
          for(String s:listItems){
        cashModal=new CashModal();
        String x[]=s.split("\\*");
        cashModal.setCount(Integer.parseInt(x[0].trim()));
        cashModal.setCurrency(Integer.parseInt(x[1].split("\\=")[0].trim()));
        cashModal.setSubTotal(Integer.parseInt(x[1].split("\\=")[1].trim()));
        cashModals.add(cashModal);
        subTotal=subTotal+Integer.parseInt((x[1].split("\\=")[1]).trim());
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: i want to remove same currency from list cashModals,also want to increment the count, subtotal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Map for maintaining data.The key would be the currency field.Try this code:

```
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        listItems.add("1 * 10 = 10");
        listItems.add("2 * 10 =  20");
        listItems.add("1 * 5 = 5");
        listItems.add("2 * 10 = 20");

        Map<Integer, CashModal> cashModalsMap = new HashMap<Integer, CashModal>();
        int subTotal = 0;
        int existingCount = 0;
        int existingSubtotal = 0;
        for (String s : listItems) {
            String x[] = s.split("\\*");
            if (!cashModalsMap
                    .containsKey(Integer.parseInt(x[1].split("\\=")[0].trim()))) {
                CashModal cashModal = new CashModal();

                cashModal.setCount(Integer.parseInt(x[0].trim()));
                cashModal.setCurrency(Integer.parseInt(x[1].split("\\=")[0]
                        .trim()));
                cashModal.setSubTotal(Integer.parseInt(x[1].split("\\=")[1]
                        .trim()));
                cashModalsMap.put(
                        Integer.parseInt(x[1].split("\\=")[0].trim()),
                        cashModal);
                subTotal = subTotal
                        + Integer.parseInt((x[1].split("\\=")[1]).trim());
            } else {
                CashModal cashModalExisting = cashModalsMap.get(Integer
                        .parseInt(x[1].split("\\=")[0].trim()));
                existingCount = cashModalExisting.getCount();
                existingSubtotal = cashModalExisting.getSubTotal();
                cashModalExisting.setCount(existingCount
                        + Integer.parseInt(x[0].trim()));
                cashModalExisting.setSubTotal(existingSubtotal
                        + Integer.parseInt(x[1].split("\\=")[1].trim()));
                cashModalsMap.put(
                        Integer.parseInt(x[1].split("\\=")[0].trim()),
                        cashModalExisting);
            }
        }
        for(CashModal cm:cashModalsMap.values()){
        System.out.println("Count:"+cm.getCount()+",Currency:"+cm.getCurrency()+",SubTotal:"+cm.getSubTotal());
        }
    }
```